# USB-C Thunderbolt 3 port not working HP Spectre x360 15-df0322ng

Tags: usb, hp-spectre

The rear USB-C Thunderbolt 3 Port of my HP Spectre x360 15-df0322ng suddenly stopped working. Basic USB-C functionality like connecting my smartphone still works, but I cannot connect my monitor or keyboard via the HP Spectre USB-C travel dock anymore. The LED of the dock does not light up either.

The other USB-C port is still working fine (dock LED is on even if PC is turned off and all connected periphery is working fine).

Neither restarting nor updating drivers (Windows 10) and BIOS did the trick so far.

Answer (score 3):

Got it:

1. Turn off the system
2. Press and hold <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>Power button</kbd> for at least 5 seconds

Some forums suggested to turn off the system and then just press and hold the power button for at least 5 seconds which did not work for me. Adding <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> did the trick! The shortcut is said to reset the embedded controller. The dock's LED immediately turned on and upon booting everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After several attempts suggested by the HP SUPPORT (reinstall drivers, bios, and even the operating  system!) they gave me the correct procedure. You can find it in this post in the HP community:"External monitor not working with thunderbolt connector". However I report it below:

You need to go to the device manager, then Graphic cards, and choose the one related to the external monitor (in my case the NVIDIA one). Right click, properties, details, GUID class, and take note of the code.

Now enter the REGEDIT and enter the following directory: \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\

finally choose the folder with the same name of the code you took note befeore, then choose folder 0002 and set the RMEnablePhyRepeater entry to 1 (in my case it was set to 0). Shut down the laptop and switch it on.
That's it!

Comment: This also fixed it for me on an HP Omen 15.  Tried the hold power button trick which seems to work with other HP devices, but this fix worked.  Note that the `0002` may not necessarily match with what's on your system.  In my case, it was folder `0000` so just find the key and change the value and reboot.  Saved me a lot of angst!